# How to listen to when a checkbox is checked in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to know when any checkbox on the page is checked:

e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox">
```

I tried this in Jquery

```
$('input type=["checkbox"]').change(function(){
alert('changed');
});
```

But it didn't work, any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that `$('input type=["checkbox"]')` is not a valid selector. It should be `$('input[type=checkbox]')` instead. Even better though would be `$('input:checkbox')`. ;)

Answer (score 146):

Use the `change()` event, and the `is()` test:

```
$('input:checkbox').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('checked');
        }
    });
```

I've updated the above, to the following, because of my silly reliance on jQuery (in the `if`) when the DOM properties would be equally appropriate, and also cheaper to use. Also the selector has been changed, in order to allow it to be passed, in those browsers that support it, to the DOM's `document.querySelectorAll()` method:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(
    function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            alert('checked');
        }
    });
```

For the sake of completion, the same thing is also easily possible in plain JavaScript:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'),
    checkboxArray = Array.from( checkboxes );

function confirmCheck() {
  if (this.checked) {
    alert('checked');
  }
}

checkboxArray.forEach(function(checkbox) {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', confirmCheck);
});
```

---

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
- jQuery:

  - [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

Comment: Can you guarantee that the change event will only be triggered on a check state change, not others like visibility, etc?

Comment: @committedandroider: "*[Can I] guarantee...?*" - no, but I will definitely say that I've never had a change event fire for anything other than a user-interaction with either the check-box or its associated `<label>` element (unless I'm programaticaly triggering the change event for some reason).

Answer (score 22):

```
$('input:checkbox').live('change', function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert('checked');
    } else {
        alert('un-checked');
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Zg3x/1/

Comment: Why `.live`? Why not `.click`?

Comment: Since I do not know how/when the input element is being added to the dom, using .live() for examples helps them be relevant even if dynamic injection of the element is occurring. In a general sense, .live() will apply to elements "now and in the future" (as the docs put it) and .click() is a shortcut for .bind('click', function() {}) which only applies to elements already in the dom.

Comment: @Jasper: `live` is way slower than the normal bind, because the event should bubble up. It makes much more sense to use the `change` event bound directly to the element, if the latter is a static one.

Comment: Yeah after thinking about it I agree that it is probably a bad default for me to demonstrate with. I was wondering what kind of overhead each of them creates and I got some mixed results from jsperf (http://jsperf.com/livevsbind2). .bind() (as you would imagine) generally gave a nice performance increase (15-25%) but in IE 8 they were about the same and in Opera .live() was quicker.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, you would want to use .on() instead of .bind() or .live(). More info here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @JDSmith That's a good point, in jQuery 1.7+ `.live()` is just a shortcut to `.on()`. Are you aware if `.live()` has been completely removed from jQuery 1.9?

Comment: Per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/), `.live()` has been completely removed as of 1.9.

Answer (score 17):

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert('Checked');
    }
});
```

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/E6RS9/)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to use .on this works

```
 jQuery('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
   if (this.checked) {
     console.log('checked');
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
   if(this.checked)
      alert('checked');
   else
      alert('not checked');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){

alert($(this).val());

});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SXph5/

[**`jquery change`**](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    alert("checked"); 
});
```

Just a normal `.click` will do.