# triggering a checkbox when checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to listen to when a checkbox is checked in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878757/how-to-listen-to-when-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

I'm creating a number of checkboxes dynamically using JQuery as shown below.

```
     function createCheckbox(len){

        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            $('#checkboxes').append('<input type="checkbox" ' + 'id=' + i + '></input>');
        }
        return;
      }
```

In the HTML, I have:

```
<div id="checkboxes"></div>
```

My goals is whenever a checkbox is checked, to be able to send  it's id (or value) to this function:

```
function hideColumn(columnIndex){
        $('#chart2 td:nth-child(' + (columnIndex+1) + ')').hide(); 
        return;
      }
```

Which will be able to handle the logic of hidding a particular column in my table.
Could somone please help me with that?
Thanks

Comment: `trigger`, `onclick`, verify if the box has been checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you can try this,just by modify createCheckbox function:

```
function createCheckbox(len){
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        $('<input type="checkbox" ' + 'id=' + i + '></input>').on('change', function(e) {
            if (this.checked) {
                hideColumn(this.id);
            }
        }).appendTo($('#checkboxes'));
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Just one more thing .. how do I do to delete `this` after it has been selected?

Comment: I mean, removing the checkbox altogether?

Comment: $("#checkboxes :checkbox").remove()

Answer (score 1):

As you're creating `checkbox` dynamically so you've to use delegate event using jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

```
$('#checkboxes').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
  if( this.checked ) {
    hideColumn( this.id ); // to send value use:   this.value
                           // but in your append code 
                           // there is no value attribute
  }
});
```

#### Note

Syntax of `.on()` for delegate event is like:

```
$( StaticElement ).on( eventName, target, handlerFunction );
```

Where, `StaticElement` refers to an element that is not dynamic.

Comment: I think you got the selectors the wrong way round...

Comment: It's not working.. I see selects the checkbox objects, but they don't trigger a function

Comment: @philippe As Felix already pointed out, the selectors are the wrong way around. `#checkboxes` is your static element, and `:checkbox` is the selector for elements that should trigger the callback.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry Sir, bad mistake. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Sorry Sir, bad mistake. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?:

```
$("#checkboxes :checkbox").on('change', function(e) {
    if (this.checked) {
        hideColumn(this.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems very simple in jQuery API!

```
function createCheckbox(len) {    
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {        
    $('<input type="checkbox" ' + 'id=' + i + '></input>').on('change', function(e) {
      if (this.checked) {
        hideColumn(this.id);
      }
    }).appendTo($('#checkboxes'));
  }
  return; 
}
```