# Ruby on Rails: Jquery/ajax dynamic form fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, dynamic-forms

I'm in the process of implementing dynamic form fields. So far, I have some jQuery that does the trick, however I have to manually refresh the page to see the change.

How can I make this dynamic? I'm under the impression I'll need to include ajax somewhere, but I'm having issues finding good resources.

Here is the code I'm using;

```
jQuery ->
    $(
        if ($('#subject_enrolled').val() == '0')
            $('#subject_reason_not_enrolled').show()
        else
            $('#subject_reason_not_enrolled').hide();
    );
```

Any help/resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `#subject_enrolled` is a checkbox.  You just need to listen for the change events on that checkbox and then update the display of your `#subject_reason_not_enrolled`.  This is covered quite a bit in other posts.  Here's one: [How to listen to when a checkbox is checked in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878757/how-to-listen-to-when-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be what I was looking for. I'm using a drop down select (f.select), with multiple options. I think I'm on the right track with "select option:selected".