# Execute Loop on Check Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to execute a loop when a checkbox is checked
when i click the #testone, the checkbox get checked but the if doesn't get executed?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('#testone').click(function() {
     jQuery('input[value="15"]').prop("checked", true);
     if (jQuery('input[value="15"]').is(':checked')) {
           postcategories.push(checked);
           jQuery('.texts').html(postcategories);

     }
  });
```

Comment: If the checkbox gets checked then the if will get executed too. I tested that and only checked is undefined. Probably you wan't to push something else, like the string 'checked' to the array?

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `jQuery()` use `$()` second you can use an event listener to check if it's checked.
[How to listen to when a checkbox is checked in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878757/how-to-listen-to-when-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)
this post has a lot of great answers.

Comment: *"don't use `jQuery()`"*. Why not?

Comment: it's much shorter to use $. It's the convention even the jquery docs use.

Comment: Fine ... but suppose the page is using `noConflict()` such as in a wordpress template? If you make such a statement in an answer it is best to clarify why you make it and what the implications are. Also just providing links to other answers is really not an approriate way to answer as oulined in [answer]

Comment: thanks already figure it out, the var check was missing